# prevent form submission and display error message

Tags: jquery

I'm still relatively new to using jquery and I'm trying to prevent a form submission if any values in a list of records have a quantity of zero and display a single message that identifies which record(s) have a zero quantity.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        j$('[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function(e){
            j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function(index){
                if(j$(this).text() == '0') {
                    j$("#contentQtyError").css({"display":"inline"});
                    j$(this).parent().parent().css({"background-color":"#FFFFCC"});
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
    });  

</script>
```

I've captured the button click and I've also successfully trapped if one of the values in the list is zero.  How do I stop the form from submitting if one of the values is zero?  Do I use the preventDefault() method?  Also, how do I display a message on the page that indicates which row(s) (record(s)) was the one that has a zero quantity?  It would be ideal to highlight the row(s) that have a zero quantity.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should bind event with form submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('[id$=btnSubmit]').submit(function(e){
        console.log('************** we clicked the submit button');
        j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function(index){
            if(j$(this).val() == 0) {
                console.log('************* value is zero');
                 e.preventDefault(); //it will prevent the form submission
                //below will display the warning message
                j$(this).append("<span class='message'>this value can not be left blank</span>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and help!  It guided me to a solution that is working nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your validation with form submit event. Either use `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to prevent default action

```
j$(document).on('submit', 'form#YourFormID', function (e) {
    console.log('************** we clicked the submit button');
    j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function (index) {
        if (j$(this).val() == 0) {
            console.log('************* value is zero');

            //To prevent form submission
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Note: In place of `form#YourFormID'` provide correct selector. If your have single form only `form` will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Try [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {
   //Assuming you have only one form in the document, if not change the selector to be specific to the form you want to target.
    j$('form').on('submit', function(e){
        console.log('************** the form is being submitted');
        j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function(index){
            if(j$(this).val() == 0) {
                console.log('************* value is zero');
                e.preventDefault();  
            }
        });
    });
});
```